# Create a dictionary inside nested lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Can someone explain how can I construct a dictionary inside lists? For example, I have this dictionary:

```
A = {'typeA': [12], 'typeB': [12, 13]}
```

and I want to get this:

```
A = {'typeA': [{12: []}], 'typeB': [{12: []}, {13: []}]}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
listFinal = []
for key in A.keys
---- newDict = {}
---- for value in A[key]:
--------- newDict[value] = []
newDict[key].append(value)
```

But this isn't right...
This can be a little confusing and I believe it isn't that elegant. I'm sorry if this isn't a relevant question.

Comment: To make this a bit more on-topic, please share what were your efforts so far and what went wrong with them

Comment: if your enumerations are being this complicated...create objects to meet your business need...it'll be easier to code...and easier to maintain future development

Comment: Do you want to *transform* the first to the second? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Will those values be populated in future or else I don't think there's a necessity of a dictionary inside list.

Comment: All you're missing is one line after the second `for` loop (and inside the first): `A[key] = [newDict]`

Comment: @Autin yes, those values will be populated in future...

Comment: @Tomerikoo the dictionary gives me keyError...

Comment: @Sofia it works fine for me, only that it produces `'typeB': [{12: [], 13: []}]` instead of `'typeB': [{12: []}, {13: []}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to "transform" each *item* in each *value* to a single-element dict with an empty list, you can do:

```py
A = {'typeA': [12], 'typeB': [12, 13]}

for lst in A.values():
    for i, val in enumerate(lst):
        lst[i] = {val: []}

print(A)
```

Gives:

```
{'typeA': [{12: []}], 'typeB': [{12: []}, {13: []}]}
```

---

Going with your initial line-of-thought you probably meant for something similar to:

```py
for key in A.keys():
    listFinal = []
    for value in A[key]:
        newDict = {value: []}
        listFinal.append(newDict)
    A[key] = listFinal
```

Which gives the same output

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is really usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with dict comprehensions

```
a = {key: [{v: []} for v in A[key]] for key in A.keys()}

# outout {'typeA': [{12: []}], 'typeB': [{12: []}, {13: []}]}
```

Another version

```
a = {key: [{v: []} for v in value] for key, value in A.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will meet your requirement

```
A = {'typeA': [12], 'typeB': [12, 13]}
result = {}
for item in A.items():
    result[item[0]] = [dict.fromkeys(item[1], [])]
print(result)
# {'typeA': [{12: []}], 'typeB': [{12: [], 13: []}]}
```

Comment: A little warning: using `fromkeys` with an empty list as the value will use **the same list** for all keys. Which is probably unwanted. This is also warned about in the docs. For example, doing `A['typeB'][0][12].append(0)` will also append `0` to the list of key `13`